# MS Access Table Design for Employees with different training requirements

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Please help with me a conceptual problem I've been trying to figure out for the past 3 days now.  I'm trying to use Access to centralize the tracking of training that was previously done on separate excel spreadsheets.  I have about ~340 employees that are categorized into 12 different positions all with varying degrees of required training.  I have an example below:

**Position 1:** Class A, Class B, Class C
**Position 2:** Class A, Class B
**Position 3:** Class A
**Position 4:** Class A

As you can see, all 340 personnel require the Class A training.  But only some positions require the Class B or even Class C.  Right now I have a single table with the individuals name and associated contact information and all 12 possible classes.  All I want access to do is store the date they've completed training, nothing else.  The problem that I'm running into is that the Date/Time field cannot distinguish between someone that is required to take that class and simply hasn't done it yet (a null value) vs. someone that is not required to take the class and obviously hasn't completed it (also a null value).

What I've tried:

-A query using calculated fields that will enter in the value "NOT REQ" if the job position does not require the training.  An example is below:
**HAZMAT Inspector: IIf([POSITION]="Load Planner",[HAZ Inspector],"NOT REQ")**
Why it doesn't work:  Inserting text into the field changes it from a date to a text field so I can no longer use Date functions to determine if training is expired.  Also, I cannot edit the field on a form and save it back to the original table due to it being a calculated field.
Possible Solution(?):  Use a SQL Update statement in VBA to write the value of a calculated field back into the original table?  I still run into the problem that I cannot update the field to begin with on the form...

-Separate Tables for each Position(?):  The main problem I see with this is that a lot of positions require the same exact class so I'd be entering in a lot of redundant information.

-Separate Tables for each Class (?):  I can see how I'd be safer with this route, but for it to be useful I'd imagine I'd have to write some type of VBA code that says when I assign someone to Position X, his Employee ID is automatically populated in Tables A, B, & C based on his position's training requirements.  Is that doable?  Is this the best option, or am I just off the mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already explained, you cannot make entries in a calculated field. You will need a different approach. The approach depends if you display only one employee per form (`Single Form`) or if you display a list of employees (`Continuous Form` or `Datasheet`).

On a `Single Form` I would simply disable the fields which do not apply

```
me!txtClassBDate.Enabled = me!txtPosition = 2
```

You can call this code from `Form_Current` and possibly in the `AfterUpdate` of a control used to change the position type.

---

The other possibility is to use conditional formatting. Select the date-`TextBox`; then open menu "Format" > "Conditional Formatting..." (I do not know where that is on the ribbons of Acc 2007+). Here you can define the appearance of the control depending on the evaluation of an expression. You can also set the control in a disabled state.